How do I prevent user from closing Picamera2 preview window?
I'm building a Python/Tkinter app that involves displaying a Picamera2 preview window. I don't want the user to be able to close the preview window; rather, I want to close it programmatically, because there is some clean-up that's required. I know how to do this with the main window by calling root.protocol ("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", swallow_event), where swallow_event is just a 'pass' statement. I want to set this callback only for the image preview window served up by Picamera2; not the %kinter root window.
I've tried Google searches. Nothing turns up exactly what I'm trying to do.

Can you provide a [mre]? For this question, that would probably mean a bare-bones script that creates a Tkinter app, the preview window, and maybe one more thing that you want to avoid closing.
